# Any way to get an AMD HD4250 Graphics to work in 13.10 with good performance? Mine gets slower until unusable

Tags: drivers, 13.10, ati, graphics, performance

I have an ASUS M5A88-V EVO motherboard with an integrated AMD/ATI RS880[Radeon HD4250].

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 64bit and it seems to get slower until it is unusable.    Especially the graphics animations, ie switching windows.

I checked and it is using the Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS880 driver.

Is that the right one and is there something that needs to be done to get it to work correctly?

The only thing I have seen suggested in other places is to go back to a version before 12.10. That seems impractical at this point.  Is there any reason to expect it will work in 14.04 LTS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to 14.04 - the latest kernel enables dynamic power management by default, which means the GPU clock frequency is automatically increased in order to get better performance. Without DPM the clock rate is left at whatever the BIOS originally set it to.

Comment: Thanks, I would but 14.04 will not support configuring multiple monitors when the are on multiple video cards. Is this really specific to 14.04 or is it specific to a specific kernel version/module version

Comment: Hmmm old answer.  You could try just upgrading the kernel, 4.0 would be a good choice, but Ubuntu 13.10 was EOL July 2014, it would be a good idea to upgrade to a newer supported release. Multiple video card setups generally do not work well for a single accelerated desktop, it would be easier to just buy a proper multi-monitor video card e.g. AMD/ATI Eyefinity for up to 6 monitors.